# How to measure DC current RPi?

Tags: gpio, python, hardware, electronics, measuring

I have recently bought a Raspberry Pi, and I would like to be able to measure the current flowing through the circuit in our [Greenpower](http://www.greenpower.co.uk/) electric racing car. It would also be useful to record this for future analysis, ideally using Python. I have looked at using an [4 channel 16-bit ADC](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1085) but I am not clear on how to use it and whether it would actually do what I want. It could be measuring up to 60 Amps and 24 Volts.

Comment: You are talking about quite a lot of power.  I doubt this is the right forum to answer the question.

Comment: Refer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ for the hardware part to get more and better answers. Feel free to discuss issues of the python scripting back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 10-bit 2-channel ADC, `MCP 3002`. It's quite easy:
In this tutorial, he uses it to measure battery, but with a bit of creativity it can be used to measure other things too. Here it is: http://raspi.tv/2013/controlled-shutdown-duration-test-of-pi-model-a-with-2-cell-lipo

Answer (score 3):

Note that ADC is only a part of the solution, and not really specific to the problem. Measurements of currents exceeding hundreds of milliamperes are typically done using [Hall sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor):

[image]

These sensors react to magnetic field near the current-carrying conductor which is proportional to the current.

For currents exceeding 50A, you're going to need something like an [ACS758](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/allegro-microsystems-llc/ACS758LCB-100U-PFF-T/620-1354-ND/2415199):

[image]